# What is "ndptsp.tsp"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, anti-virus, rootkit, sophos

Sophos Anti-Rootkit tells me that on one of our web servers, there is an "unknown hidden file" `ndptsp.tsp`:

```
Area:        Local hard drives
Description: Unknown hidden file 
Location:    C:\Windows\System32\ndptsp.tsp
Removable:   Yes (but clean up not recommended for this file)
Notes:       (no more detail available)
```

Doing a [Google search for the term](http://www.google.com/search?q=ndptsp.tsp), it shows me hundreds of auto-generated, useless pages.

**My question is:**

Is this something to worry about or is this simply a false-positive which I can safely ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have been a false positive with "ndptsp.exe", which is normally used by a worm.

The real ndptsp.tsp is a Windows binaries, as per the explanation on it below:

> NDPTSP NDPTSP ( Ndptsp.tsp) is a service provider DLL that runs in the
>   context of the TAPI service process. NDPTSP provides a TSPI interface
>   that the TAPI service presents to TAPI-aware applications so that
>   NDPROXY can communicate with user-mode applications. NDPTSP works with
>   NDPROXY to convert user-mode requests to TAPI connection-oriented OIDs
>   (OID_CO_TAPI_ Xxx). For more information about TAPI
>   connection-oriented OIDs, see TAPI Extensions for Connection-Oriented
>   NDIS.

[Source from MSDN on RAS Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)